# Get a prompt to confirm each time a file is opened by any application

Tags: files, virtual-file-system

I've got a file that contains information I need to let some apps read sometimes, but would generally prefer it's not accessed without me knowing about it.

How can I get the file descriptor open operation to prompt me for confirmation before it succeeds?

I could write my own file system emulator and mount it probably, but that sounds like too much.

Are there existing tools for that?

Comment: "I could write my own file system emulator and mount it probably" - a FUSE plug-in might work there too.

Answer (score 2):

You could monitor access but not deny it with something like `inotifywait`.

You could deliver the file contents to *stdout* by means of a small `sudo`-controlled script that mediated access to the restricted file.

I know of nothing that will do precisely what you want, but the beauty here is that you can build something similar to your required tool with existing utilities.